# How would I modify the footnote marker at the bottom of the page only?

Tags: footnotes

I have a book wherein groupings of footnotes will use letters as marks (i.e., a, b, c, etc.).  However, new groupings that start again will be common on a single page.  Each grouping is numbered using a counter, and this counter is shown on the printed page.  I would like the footnotes to appear normally inline, but I would like to attach the counter value to each "a" footnote in the footer.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{grouping}
\newcommand{\newGrouping}{\stepcounter{grouping}\textsuperscript{\arabic{grouping}}\setcounter{footnote}{0}}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\newGrouping This is some example text.\footnote{First example footnote.}
Some more text\footnote{Second example footnote.} and yet more.\footnote{Third example footnote.}
\newGrouping Now with a new grouping,\footnote{First example footnote in second grouping.}
there is some ambiguity about which footnote\footnote{Second example footnote in second grouping.}
is intended.\footnote{Third example footnote in second grouping.}

\end{document}
```

What I would like is for the first "a" footnote to show as 1a at the bottom and the second to show as 2a.  I tried to replace `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}` with the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\ifnum\value{footnote}>1\alph{footnote}\else\arabic{\grouping}{\alph{footnote}\fi}
```

This did the opposite of what I intended.  It left the bottom alone and added the grouping number inline.

I tried to attach an image, but it was not working.  Here is the link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QzuE.jpg

Comment: The manyfoot package provide footnotes using multiple formats.  Not by groups, but by name; e.g. \footnoteA \footnoteB, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footnote at the bottom of the page is typeset by the internal LaTeX command `\@makefntext`. In the `book` document class it's defined as:

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
```

where `\@makefnmark` creates the actual footnote marker and is defined as:

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

We can't just redefine `\@makefnmark` because that gets used in both the footnote text at the bottom of the page and the marker in the body text so we have to make the change to `\@makefntext` instead.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\thegrouping\@thefnmark}}}#1}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This worked wonders.  I suggested an edit (which evidently will need to be reviewed), because it seems you inadvertently changed `\@thefnmark` to `\@thefntmark`.  I also found this did exactly what I wanted when I changed `\thegrouping\@thefntmark` to `\ifnum\value{footnote}>1\@thefnmark\else\thegrouping\@thefnmark\fi`.  Accepting this answer now.