# Redefine footnote marker text using three-column footnotes from reledmac package

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I got a great answer for how to change only the footnote marker at the bottom of the page here: [How would I modify the footnote marker at the bottom of the page only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588119/how-would-i-modify-the-footnote-marker-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-only).  However I am using three-column footnote provided from the reledmac package.  While the accepted answer solved the problem using the MWE I provided there, it does not work in the specific situation I am facing.  I tried to dig into the reledmac package to find where the definitions are to make the appropriate `\renewcommand` call, but I am in way over my head there.  Here is my updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\newcounter{grouping}
\newcommand{\newGrouping}{\stepcounter{grouping}\textsuperscript{\arabic{grouping}}\setcounter{footnoteA}{0}}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\newGrouping This is some example text.\footnote{First example footnote.}
Some more text\footnote{Second example footnote.} and yet more.\footnote{Third example footnote.}
\newGrouping Now with a new grouping,\footnote{First example footnote in second grouping.}
there is some ambiguity about which footnote\footnote{Second example footnote in second grouping.}
is intended.\footnote{Third example footnote in second grouping.}

\end{document}
```

What I need is for the "a" footnotes at the bottom of the page to show "1a", "2a", etc.  Simply adding this code to the file header does nothing, presumably because `\@makefntext` is not called by `\footnoteA` like it is for `\footnote`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \parindent 1em%
        \noindent
        \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\ifnum\value{footnote}>1\@thefnmark\else\thenewverse\@thefnmark\fi}}}#1}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper, I came up with the solution I needed.  Adding this code to the header gives the desired output:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\normalfootfootmarkX}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ifnum\value{footnoteA}>1\@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}\else\thegrouping\@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}\fi}}
\makeatother
```